# Stripping time from datetime in Sort

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working in VBA for Excel. Got the following raw data:

```
**TIME**                  **PRICE**
04-02-2013  10:36:00        560
04-02-2013  12:40:00        600
03-02-2013  16:10:00        612
```

I need an efficient and trustworthy method of stripping the time from the datetime **TIME** and then sorting on **TIME** NEWEST first and **PRICE** DESCENDING second. Desired output:

```
**TIME**                  **PRICE**
04-02-2013                  600
04-02-2013                  560
03-02-2013                  612
```

Simply changing the column format and forcing DD-MM-YYYY *does not work*. I've tried a few things myself, for example by converting the column to TEXT and stripping the time by removing every thing after the decimals in the displayed datetime-values, but it didn't work out. I hope you can help me!

Comment: Can you post any of your code? If TIME is a date in a cell, you should be able to use `Floor` or `RoundDown` to get the date.

Comment: Sam, it seems to be doing the stripping as it should, but using worksheet functions is so messy. Is there no programmatic way of accomplishing the same? Using worksheet functions I have to 1: Insert the function in entirely new column, 2: Copy-pastespecial same column as VALUE, 3: Delete original column.

Compare that to a simple loop through the entire worksheet that replaces each date with its stripped brother *in a single phase*. Am I making sense?

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(val,0)` will work in vba. where val is a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Simply changing the column format and forcing DD-MM-YYYY does not work.

Since like your date/time is stored as text. Try this

`=TEXT(A1,"DD/MM/YYYY")`

[image]

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS**

I am able to get the desired out by simple sorting?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it unfortunately doesn't work: http://tinyurl.com/o6e6dqb
Using =TEXT(A1,"DD-MM-YYYY") Changing hyphen to forward slash doesn't make any difference.

I would also prefer if it was a programmatic solution.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't match with the data in your question?

Comment: I changed the displayed format to "DD-MM-YYYY". The actual cell value remains datetime: http://i.imgur.com/6NCSkKD.png

Comment: What you are saying now is totally different that what you asked in your question above... So you don't want to display the time in formula bar now. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't think I am saying anything differently. The SORT-function will include the hours, minutes and seconds no matter what cell date-format (Right-click, Format cells)  is assigned. The problem is that the actual value of the cell remains the same - Excel sorts on hh:mm:ss regardless of the format I assign.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41651/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-khh)

Answer (score 0):

To get just the date of a date time you can use the formula:

```
=Int(A1)
```

[image]

Then simply Right click the column and format:

[image]

Select Date and the format you want and then ok:

[image]

Then you are left with this| :

[image]